# How to make a shapefile (which is not grid aligned) to grid aligned in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have shapefile which is not grid aligned. I want it to be grid aligned. Doing it manually will consume lot of time. Is there any better way to make the shapefile to grid aligned?

[image]

Comment: What do u call 'not grid aligned' ? ... u have tools in QGIS that will create a grid according to your map's extent ... the grid will be aligned with your map but u don't have to "shift or move" your map ...

Comment: too vague - can you explain what you want a bit better, or with a diagram

Comment: Thank you for the response, i have added an image relating to this.

Comment: why don't you just make a grid, then make a shapefile of that grid?

Comment: Because of different sources used to create map, it happened that way and yes that was the problem we are facing, any tools available in QGIS to correct it out?

Comment: From the icon in the added image you seem using QGIS 2 (such as 2.18). Is it possible for you to upgrade it to QGIS 3? It will give you `Snap geometries to layer` tool.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Kazuhito, i will try this out and get back to you!

Answer (score 1):

The [MMQGIS](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/) plugin can create grids from scratch for you, assuming that is what you are looking for. This will probably be easier than trying to correct an existing misalignment issue, unless you also need to transfer attributes?